# Crossdomain Issue while accessing Linkedin enabled Silverlight Application from hosted environment

Tags: silverlight, linkedin-api

I am developing a linkedin enabled Silverlight application. LinkedIn API calls are made through Oauth2 over REST platform. I am able to fetch authorization code,access token and make API calls while running the application as "localhost" or in local IIS. However, when I try to access the deployed application outside the environment with Public IP, I am unable to make LinkedIn API calls. While debugging with Fiddler, the trace shows that "crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml" not found in http://www.linkedin.com/crossdomain.xml. I am unsure why this problem occurs only when we try accessing the hosted application outside and doesn't occur while running under localhost. I have tried placing both these xml files in the root folder of IIS and also inside our application hosted folder. Looking forward for your kind suggestions/help resolving this.

Thanks,
Subbu